# Allowing a non-root user to drop cache

Tags: linux, sudoers, clear-cache

I am carrying out performance tests on a system where I need to ensure I am reading data from the disk, and that it is not just cached (say from earlier tests). I read [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html) that I can drop cache with the command

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

However, note that even though my account is an admin account (login peter), it still requires my password. I want to be able to run this in a batch script without the requirement to input a password (as this is obviously manual)

More [research](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821) led me to the sudoers file. My plan was to place the above command into a one line script called dropCache, and edit sudoers so that I could run it without entering a password. So I added the line

```
ALL ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/peter/dropCache
```

at the end of my sudoers file (using visudo). With my admin account, if I run

```
sudo -l
```

I get

```
(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/peter/dropCache
```

However, if I run my dropCache script I still get asked for my password

```
./dropCache
[sudo] password for peter:
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I did when I needed this was I wrote a small C program, changed the owner of the compiled file to root, and set the setuid bit.

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

extern void sync(void);

int main(void) {
    if (geteuid() != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "flush-cache: Not root\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Flushing page cache, dentries and inodes...\n");
    // First: the traditional three sync calls. Perhaps not needed?
    // For security reasons, system("sync") is not a good idea.
    sync();
    sync();
    sync();
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "flush-cache: Couldn't open /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fprintf(f, "3\n") != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "flush-cache: Couldn't write 3 to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("Done flushing.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks Thomas - you deserve your high reputation score

Comment: This executable is a security risk - you don't set your PATH and run an external command without an absolute path name. You can just call sync() system call directly instead of running the external sync command.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Ubuntu 21.04 and it works:
Step 1: create a small script like below (assuming the name to be clear_drop_cacahes.sh):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Run a sync to reduce dirty caches
sync

# Tell the OS to clear caches
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Step 2: make the script executable: `chmod 744 clear_drop_caches.sh`

Step 3: need to do this with someone with sudo right:

`sudo visudo`

Add the following line (to the end of the file)

```
ALL      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path-to-the-small-script/clear_drop_caches.sh
```

Step 4: now any user can run the drop caches script like below:

```
sudo /path-to-the-small-script/clear_drop_caches.sh
```

I am not sure about the security of doing something like this.